# Hibernate Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key on many-to-many

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm trying to implement given database structure with JPA
[image]

SQL scripts:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS StudentLesson;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS StudentCourse;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Lesson;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Course;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Student;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Course
(
    courseId    BIGINT       NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name        VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT         NULL,
    actual      TINYINT      NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (courseId)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lesson
(
    lessonId    BIGINT       NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    courseId    BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    orderNumber INTEGER      NULL,
    actual      TINYINT      NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (lessonId),
    CONSTRAINT FK__Lesson__courseId FOREIGN KEY Lesson (courseId) REFERENCES Course (courseId)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student
(
    studentId BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userId    BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (studentId),
    CONSTRAINT FK__Student__userId FOREIGN KEY Student (userId) REFERENCES User (userId)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentCourse
(
    studentCourseId  BIGINT        NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    studentId        BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    courseId         BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    percentCompleted DECIMAL(5, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    PRIMARY KEY (studentCourseId),
    CONSTRAINT FK__StudentCourse__studentId FOREIGN KEY StudentCourse (studentId) REFERENCES Student (studentId),
    CONSTRAINT FK__StudentCourse__courseId FOREIGN KEY StudentCourse (courseId) REFERENCES Course (courseId)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentLesson
(
    studentLessonId  BIGINT        NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    studentCourseId  BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    lessonId         BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    percentCompleted DECIMAL(5, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    PRIMARY KEY (studentLessonId),
    CONSTRAINT FK__StudentLesson__studentCourseId FOREIGN KEY StudentLesson (studentCourseId) REFERENCES StudentCourse (studentCourseId),
    CONSTRAINT FK__StudentLesson__lessonId FOREIGN KEY StudentLesson (lessonId) REFERENCES Lesson (lessonId)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Here are my entity classes:
Student

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
@Getter
@Setter
public class StudentDBO extends AbstractDBO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "studentId", nullable = false)
    private Long studentId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    private UserDBO user;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="StudentCourse",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="studentId")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="courseId")})
    private Set<CourseDBO> courses;

}
```

Course

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Course")
@Getter
@Setter
public class CourseDBO extends AbstractDBO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "courseId", nullable = false)
    private Long courseId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "actual")
    private Boolean actual;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "course", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<LessonDBO> lessons;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="courses")
    private Set<StudentDBO> students;

}
```

Lesson

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Lesson")
@Getter
@Setter
public class LessonDBO extends AbstractOrderedDBO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "lessonId", nullable = false)
    private Long lessonId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "courseId", nullable = false)
    private CourseDBO course;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "actual")
    private Boolean actual;

}
```

StudentCourse

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "StudentCourse")
@Getter
@Setter
public class StudentCourseDBO extends AbstractDBO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "studentCourseId", nullable = false)
    private Long studentCourseId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "studentId", nullable = false)
    private StudentDBO student;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "courseId", nullable = false)
    private CourseDBO course;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "studentCourse")
    private Set<StudentLessonDBO> studentLessons;

    @Column(name = "percentCompleted", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal percentCompleted;

}
```

StudentLesson

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "StudentLesson")
@Getter
@Setter
public class StudentLessonDBO extends AbstractDBO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "studentLessonId", nullable = false)
    private Long studentLessonId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "studentCourseId", nullable = false)
    private StudentCourseDBO studentCourse;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lessonId", nullable = false)
    private LessonDBO lesson;

    @Column(name = "percentCompleted", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal percentCompleted;

}
```

When I'm trying to start my application, it gives me error `Foreign key (FKr8cmxbjotnbr91mtv62sakwva:StudentLesson [studentCourseId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (StudentCourse [studentId,courseId])`
Full stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKr8cmxbjotnbr91mtv62sakwva:StudentLesson [studentCourseId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (StudentCourse [studentId,courseId])
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKr8cmxbjotnbr91mtv62sakwva:StudentLesson [studentCourseId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (StudentCourse [studentId,courseId])
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:148) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1929) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1845) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1665) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

What might be the issue? Am I using many-to-many relation table StudentCourse wrong? Error says, that StudentLesson has to have more then one column reference, but in database StudentCourse has single primary key column (studentCourseId), not (studentId, courseId).

Comment: Are you sure your database is not in an outdated state "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"?

Comment: Yes, I'm executing DROP TABLE IF EXISTS each time. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

How does `AbstractDBO` look like? Maybe you are declaring an id there as well?

Comment: It's just an empty abstract class that implements  Serializable

Comment: The issue is that the Hibernate model of the table `StudentCourse` has two columns for the primary key, so this is a mapping issue on your side. Do you map the table to multiple entities? Or do you have a `@ManyToMany` somewhere where you use `StudentCourse` as join table?

Comment: StudentCourse is the product of many-to-many relation between Student and Course. Usually, StudentCourseDBO class would not even be created,  but I wanted  to use it additionally as a separate entity with additional fields and relations, one-to-many with StudentLesson in that case. Is there a way to specify primary key as one ID field rather than two many-to-many relation fields?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing, please update your question with all the details. Anyway, you can't map a table multiple times this way. If you map a table as entity, you should always use the entity when wanting to map to that table, otherwise you end up with problems like this.